# How to check for clustered unique key while inserting in SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert rows from another database table to new database table getting the below error if there is no where condition in the query.

> Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'NK_LkupxViolations'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.LkupxViolation'. The duplicate key value is (00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, (Not Specified)).

Then I wrote the below query adding where conditions it worked but it didn't insert the expected no. of rows.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'LkupxViolation')
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO dbo.[LkupxViolation] SELECT * FROM  [DMO_DB].[dbo].[LkupxViolation] where CGRootId not in (select CGRootId from dbo.[LkupxViolation])
   and Name not in (select name from dbo.[LkupxViolation])
END
ELSE 
PRINT 'LkupxViolation table does not exist'
```

The unique key in the table is created as:

```
CONSTRAINT [NK_LkupxViolations] UNIQUE CLUSTERED
(
    [CGRootId] ASC,
    [Name] ASC
)
```

Comment: Which database do you use? Code you posted doesn't look like Oracle (while you tagged the question as "Oracle11g").

Comment: @Littlefoot SQL server

Comment: Clearly the other db does not have a unique key on cgrootid/name if it has multiple identical values. Either filter them out with a Where clause, make a nonunique index or remove the key. We cannot tell you what to do because we know nothing of your business needs for this data

Comment: Check `@@ROWCOUNT` on the next line, see [here](https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern) for best practice for UPSERTs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[LkupxViolation]
    SELECT *
    FROM  [DMO_DB].[dbo].[LkupxViolation] remove_l
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM dbo.[LkupxViolation] local_l
                      WHERE local_l.Name = remote_l.Name AND
                            local_l.CGRootId = remote_l.CGRootId
                     );
```

This checks for both values in the *same* row.  In addition, `NOT IN` is not `NULL`-safe.  If *any* values generated by the subquery are `NULL` then *all* rows are filtered out.